# Solidity string slice error

Tags: solidity, remix, string

I am using a [string utility library](https://github.com/arachnid/solidity-stringutils) for Solidity with the aim of splitting a string on a specific delimiter. I followed the instructions from the library:

```
var s = someString.toSlice();
var foo = s.split("-".toSlice());

logString(foo);
```

However, I'm getting an error with the logString(). The online Solidity IDE says

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit converstion from struct strings.slice memeory to string memory requested. 
    logString(foo);
              ^-^
```

How can I properly print out the sliced portion of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `logString()` is defined, but I imagine it takes a string argument.  `split()` returns a slice, so you need to convert it to a string:

```
logString(foo.toString());
```